# Shorter proof that $qx \le r$ iff $x \le 0$ when $0 \le r < q$? (over the integers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Working with integers, I can prove that $qx \le r$ iff $x \le 0$ when $0 \le r < q$ by first going forwards to prove "if,"

$$ qx \le r$$
$$ qx < q$$
$$ x < 1$$
$$ x \le 0$$

and then by going backwards to complete it to "iff,"

$$ x \le 0$$
$$ qx \le 0$$
$$ qx \le r$$
However, the idea expressed here is much simpler if you picture it, it's that $qx$ which changes in steps of $q$ does not "care" about changes in $r$ that are smaller than $q$. I wonder if that implies there is a shorter way to prove it, for example in one sequence of steps all of which are reversible.